# C# + Information Rights Management

Tags: c#, .net, email

I need to avoid forwarding in the emails that I'm sending using .NET. I'm using Outlook and Exchange server and I read tha IRM can help me. Does anyone have any code example or know if it's possible?

Comment: That's kinda bizarre.  I'm pretty sure I can forward any email I get.  With copy/paste if necessary.

Comment: You certainly can't stop anyone from forwarding an email.... you can put a notice in the email itself telling them that doing so is against policy or something...

Comment: I found some information here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638140.aspx but I have no idea how to leverage that from code.

Comment: What version of Exchange server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be able to use the [Microsoft Outlook 2010 Primary Interop assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx) and set the [PermissionTemplateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.permissiontemplateguid.aspx) property of the [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb610623.aspx) you're sending.

Note that you'll have to know the Guid of an IRM policy that prevents forwarding of the email.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send IRM mail programmatically in Outlook 2010.  IRM mail is actually a regular mail message with an encrypted attachment, and Outlook does not expose the right API to craft the encrypted attachment and change the mail type.

The only way to do it from C# code is to use ActiveSync and send the mail in Exchange directly.  Unfortunately, as of Exchange 2010, only licensed vendors can use ActiveSync.

See http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/intellectualproperty/iplicensing/programs/exchangeactivesyncprotocol.aspx for more information.

Also, if you go down the path of setting the template guid, know that the DoNotForward template guid is hard-coded -- if it actually works (this is untested and unsupported, so you're mileage will vary) then you don't need to bother looking up the RMS template.